# macOS High Sierra 10.13 - Core Data - NSColor stops working as transformable attribute

Tags: core-data, xcode9, swift4, macos-high-sierra

After updating to macOS High Sierra 10.13 and Xcode 9, an existing, working Cocoa Application with settings of Document-Based Application and Use Core Data has stopped working.

The problem is that my application has become not to able to open its document files with an exception:

```
[error] error: -addPersistentStoreWithType:Binary configuration:(null) URL:file:///Users/xxx/Library/Autosave%20Information/Unsaved%20zzz%20Document%202.binary options:{
    NSPersistentStoreRemoveStoreOnCleanup = 1;
} ... returned error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=259 "The file couldn’t be opened because it isn’t in the correct format." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingException=Can't read binary data from file, NSUnderlyingError=0x60c00005ff20 {Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=259 "The file “Unsaved zzz Document 2.binary” couldn’t be opened because it isn’t in the correct format." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/tora/Library/Autosave Information/Unsaved zzz Document 2.binary, NSUnderlyingException=value for key 'NS.objects' was of unexpected class 'NSColor'. Allowed classes are '{(
    NSDictionary,
    NSDictionaryMapNode,
    NSArray,
    NSString,
    NSNumber,
    NSOrderedSet,
    NSCalendarDate,
    NSDate,
    NSSet,
    NSDecimalNumber,
    NSUUID,
    NSNull,
    NSURL,
    NSData
)}'.}}} with userInfo dictionary {

(omit)
```

This application uses NSColor as well as Boolean, Integer 32, Double in the file Document.xcdatamodeld. The type of NSColor is specified as Transformable which is treated with NSArchiver for encoding and NSUnarchiver for decoding through a derived class of ValueTransformer.

**Workaround:**

According to George Brown's post, macOS High Sierra has made decoding object data securer.
[iOS 11 - Core Data - UIColor no longers works as transformable attribute](https://reformatcode.com/code/objective-c/ios-11---core-data---uicolor-no-longers-works-as-transformable-attribute)

Thanks to his solution, overriding configurePersistentStoreCoordinator makes it solved.

```
class Document: NSPersistentDocument {

  override func configurePersistentStoreCoordinator(for url: URL, ofType fileType: String, modelConfiguration configuration: String?, storeOptions: [String : Any]? = nil) throws {

    var options: [String : Any] = storeOptions ?? [:]

    if #available(OSX 10.13, *) {
      let accepted_classes: NSSet = [ NSColor.self ]
      options[NSBinaryStoreSecureDecodingClasses] = accepted_classes
    }

    do {
      try super.configurePersistentStoreCoordinator(for: url, ofType: fileType, modelConfiguration: configuration, storeOptions: options)
    }
    catch let e {
      throw e
    }
  }

}
```

Please tell us your brilliant ways!

**Edited:**

Oops, one of the solutions in Swift had been already posted by Wizard of Kneup in the stackoverflow.com. It is at the very end of George Brown's post.

I saw another, incomplete George Brown's post and tried to solve by myself.
https://reformatcode.com/code/objective-c/ios-11---core-data---uicolor-no-longers-works-as-transformable-attribute

I should have found Wizard of Kneup's post before my attempt.

Thank you George Brown and Wizard of Kneup!

Comment: I experience issues when I try to saveAs. configurePersistentStoreCoordinator isn't even called. Instead the same error pops up again. Any idea?

Comment: Wizard of Kneup, I have just tried and found, as you mentioned, `configurePersistentStoreCoordinator` is not called when `saveDocumentAs:` implemented from the beginning in `NSDocument` is executed through the menu. But no error occurred in my case. Hmm. Then, `Open Recent` the saved file, the Coordinator is called. Note that `NSDocument` seems to hide a `Save As...` menu item and add `Duplicate`. I manually added `Save As For Test...` binding to `saveDocumentAs:` for reproduction. Tested with Xcode 9.2.

Comment: The intention of `configurePersistentStoreCoordinator`, in my understanding, is to protect application from malicious files trying to inject harmful class instances. So, it should be called when opening files, but there is no need to be called when saving document to a file. I know you already know that. The point might be why the error happens when `saveAs`.

Comment: The discussion above will be continued to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48699000/configurepersistentstorecoordinator-not-called-for-saveas-nspersistentdocument